# SqlBulkCopy with multiple files

Tags: c#, sql-server

There are many examples on the use of the SqlBulkCopy Class in System.Data.SqlClient but only in relation to a single file. What I would like to know is how you use it when you have multiple files. I have read that it should only be used once but how do you achieve that ?. Can someone give me example of how to use SqlBulkCopy with multiple files

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` does not work on files it works on `DataRow[]`, `DataTable`, `DbDataReader`, or a `IDataReader`. The command line utility [`bcp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) works on files, is that what you where thinking of when you say "Multiple Files"? Or are you asking how to you upload multiple of one of the previous items I listed (multiple `DataTable` for example)?

Comment: Scott. I have used a foreach (multiple files) then Sqlbulkcopy with DataTable for each file. I ask this because I have around 15 xml files that need to be written to two sql tables every day. What is the most efficient way of doing this ?  PS. I am a novice

Answer (score 0):

If you are a novice you probably should call `SqlBulkCopy` in a loop and be done with it.

If you are advanced and have higher perf requirements you should pass in an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` that is a single combined stream that has the data of all files. That way you have the ability to insert a single stream of rows. This can be more efficient than many smaller inserts because the query processor can sort all rows and insert them sequentially. There are also concerns around minimal logging. Sometimes an empty destination table is required.

Comment: I am calling SqlBulkCopy for every file, as in, using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con)). Is that the correct or wrong way of doing it ?

Comment: Correct in the sense that it result in correct data. Are you concerned about something specific?

Comment: I am reading in around 450 files at a time. Is that equivalent to 450 calls to SqlBulkCopy and is that efficient ?

Comment: It depends on the table structure and server version whether multiple smaller loads are a problem. The best course of action would be to run a quick perf test which you need to do anyway sooner or later. Or, script out the table and post the code. Update: It also depends on the data. I think you should just test it.

Comment: ... post the data. How can I send it to you ?. This comment box allows only a certain number of characters. Shall I place it in the Answer Your Question box ?

Comment: No, he means run the code on your servers. It may be fast enough for your needs and you don't need anything fancy to load the data.